# How to add an environment in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, environments

For example, if I use `amsbook` document class and have the section `Problems`, how to include `problem` environments created like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, reqno, oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\section{Problems}
\begin{problem}
...% I want this part to appear also in the table of contents.
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

The chapters and sections appear in ToC and are clickable too. I want it for other environments, too.

How can I do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: what do you mean by "this part" the whole problem? or do you intend there to be a title of some sort cf the sectionheads that normally go in the tabke of contents?

Comment: Not the whole problem of course, I want it like `Problem 1...123` (page number)

Answer (score 10):

Define the `problem` environment using an inner theorem-like environment and adding the entry to the TOC.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{problemx}{Problem}[section]
\newenvironment{problem}[1][]
 {\expandafter\problemx\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else[#1]\fi
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}
    {\protect\tocsubsection{}{\theproblemx}{Problem\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\ (#1)\fi}}%
 }
 {\endproblemx}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}% subsections in toc

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Title}
\section{A}
\subsection{B}
text

\section{Problems}
\begin{problem}
What is $1+1$?
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}[Easy]
Show that every even number greater than $2$ is the sum of two prime numbers, not necessarily distinct.
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is `\tocsubsection` a macro specific to `amsbook`? When I try to use it in an `article` class document, an error occurs: `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \protect \tocsubsection`.

Comment: @PaulWintz Yes, it’s specific of `amsbook`

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, reqno, oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\let\saved@begintheorem\@begintheorem
\def\@begintheorem #1#2[#3]{%
\saved@begintheorem{#1}{#2}[{#3}]%
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Problem \theproblem: #3}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\section{Problems}

\begin{problem}[fermats last theorem]
\[x^n+y^n=z^n\]
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With this *all* theorem-like environments will be listed as problems in the TOC.

Comment: @egreg, yes I know:-), I actually started to code it as in your answer with an inner environment but thought I'd keep it simpler to highlight the addcontentsline bit. It may be there are no other theorem environments, or you do want all such environments in the toc, in which case this is simpler, if you need individual control then your version is the way to go...